# D3.js text in middle of svg circle not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a visualization of a sunburst where I'm trying to put text inside the svg circle in the middle of the sunburst. I can render the circle fine, but I'm unable to get any text to appear in the middle. I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/kh62vbf9/) as an example of my attempt, along with the js code below. I've found a few other posts here but they don't seem to fix this particular example. I've also seen how putting the element inside of a *g* tag should make it render text, and the *text* object is in the html, but no text is rendered for some reason. Let me know if there is anymore information I can provide, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Sunburst</title>

    <!-- external css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<!-- external javascript-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">          </script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js">                        </script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

    <div id="sunburst-container" class="col-9"></div>

  </div>

</div>

const svg = d3.select("#sunburst-container")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", "200px")
              .attr("height", "200px");


const g = svg.append("g")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)");

const parent = g.append("circle")
                                .attr("r", "50px")
                .attr("fill", "#ddddbb");

parent.append("g")
      .append("text")
      .text("hello world")
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
      .style('font-size', '12px')
      .attr('fill', 'white');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were adding a group and the text to the "parent" circle. I don't think SVG primitives can contain anything. Run the snippet below to see the difference.

Tip: Use the browser developer tools for debugging stuff like this – you can see where items are getting added, etc.

[image]

```js
const svg = d3.select("#sunburst-container")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "200px")
  .attr("height", "200px");


const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)");

g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", "50px")
  .attr("fill", "#ff0000");


g.append("text")
  .text("hello world")
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
  .style('font-size', '12px')
  .attr('fill', 'white');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="sunburst-container" class="col-9"></div>
```